# Oracle 19c in Windows trying to use Logminer Lack of utl_file_dir

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to start using Logminer. When i runned`@$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/dbmslm.sql;@$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/dbmslmd.sql`
it showed all successed, then when i run
`show parameter utl`
to check out initialization parameters are set it only show`create_stored_outlines`but no `utl_file_dir`, if `utl_file_dir` is necessary how could i create it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UTL_FILE_DIR is desupported in 19c. Read more on link.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/upgrd/behavior-changes-deprecated-desupport-oracle-database.html#GUID-C03F4062-9AB6-4FFE-8CF8-28F8AF014783?

You need to use directory objects. CREATE DIRECTORY admin AS '/path/somedir'

Comment: okay, thx mate.